# A attribute's name just like function.How am I get it?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I try this on codeigniter 2.1.4.

```
    $sql='SELECT COUNT(*) FROM prefix_blog_article';
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    $result = $query->result();
    $result = $result[0];
```

And then.

```
    var_dump($result);
```

I get.

```
    object(stdClass)[37]
       public 'COUNT(*)' => string '26' (length=2)
```

When I use `$result->COUNT(*)`.Report a error.How can I get it?
Must I get it by other ways?

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) AS mycount`, then select  `mycount`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also upgrade your SQL like this:

```
$sql='SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM prefix_blog_article';
```

And then access your object like this:

```
$result->count
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$result->{"COUNT(*)"}
```

Or

```
$attr = "COUNT(*)";
$result->$attr;
```

Comment: I try it. but can't work.`Undefined property: stdClass::$COUNT(*)`

Comment: It seems that you have a '$'  in the attributes name!